# Get the latest child messages and also parent messages that are childless

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

The following is the Message model

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent_message, class_name: 'Message', optional: true
  has_many :child_messages, foreign_key: :parent_message_id, class_name: "Message"
  has_many :message_participants

  scope :latest_messages_by_participant, -> (user_id) do
    select("DISTINCT ON (parent_message_id) messages.*").
        joins(:message_participants).
        where(message_participants: { user_id: user_id }).
        order("parent_message_id, created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

`message_participants` has a record for each message and the various people who have sent or received that message. It has a user_id on it.

The problem with the above `latest_messages_by_participant` scope is that it is able to get all the child messages BUT it gets only the last parent message. That is because we are calling DISINTICT ON on parent_message_id, and for childless parent messages this value is NULL and so it's just calling distinct on NULL and returns on 1 value (the last childless parent message).

How can I fetch all the latest messages including the latest child messages AND the latest childless parent message in a single query?

I'm using Rails 6 and Postgres 11.

**P.S:** I should also point out a secondary problem which is that the messages are returned in created_at ASC. The created_at DESC is able to get the latest child message but does not sort the overall collection. I can solve this by calling .reverse, but wondering if there was a way to fix that as well.

Comment: Actual table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and some sample data would be instrumental. A plain SQL statement would also hepl.

Comment: If you care about *performance*, we need some more information. Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info. Most importantly: roughly how many rows per user and message id on avg?

Comment: Thank you @ErwinBrandstetter, for now, performance is not a consideration, but will definitely evaluate when things change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `COALESCE` expression in `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY`.
And sort the result in an outer query to get your desired sort order:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (COALESCE(m.parent_message_id, m.id))
          m.*
   FROM   messages m
   JOIN   message_participants mp ON ...
   WHERE  mp.user_id = ...
   ORDER  BY (COALESCE(m.parent_message_id, m.id)), created_at DESC
   )
ORDER  BY created_at;
```

See (with detailed explanation):

- [SELECT DISTINCT ON, ordered by another column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/266568/3684)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Performance?

For *few* rows per user and message ID, `DISTINCT ON` is typically among the fastest possible solutions. For *many* rows, there are (much) faster ways. Depends on more information, as commented.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add a coalese in your distinct on & order by in order to pick the message's `id` when the `parent_message_id` is null.

```
select("DISTINCT ON (parent_message_id) messages.*")
...
order("parent_message_id, created_at DESC")
```

needs to be transformed to

```
select("DISTINCT ON (COALESCE(parent_message_id, messages.id)) messages.*")
...
order("COALESCE(parent_message_id, messages.id), created_at DESC")
```

Now, you have not provided the sample database tables & expected or a full model definition, so I'm inferring quite a few things. Here are the minimum table definitions (as I understood them), the raw sql query that would be generated by AR after my suggested modification [this is the query we want, given the schema below] & the results.

### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int primary key
, parent_message_id int references messages(id)
, created_at timestamp default current_timestamp
); 
INSERT INTO messages (id, parent_message_id) values 
  (1, NULL) -- parent message with children
, (2, 1)
, (3, 1)
, (4, NULL) -- parent message without children
, (5, NULL) -- another parent message without children
;
CREATE TABLE message_participants (
  user_id int
, message_id int references messages(id)
)
INSERT INTO message_participants values (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5);
```

### RAW SQL query that gives us the last parent or child message:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (COALESCE(parent_message_id, messages.id)) messages.*
FROM messages
JOIN message_participants ON message_participants.message_id = messages.id
WHERE message_participants.user_id = ? -- replace by user_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent_message_id, messages.id), created_at DESC
```

### Results

Given `user_id = 1`, the query above returns the result:

```
 id | parent_message_id |         created_at
----+-------------------+----------------------------
  1 |                   | 2020-05-11 13:50:00.857589
  4 |                   | 2020-05-11 13:50:00.857589
(2 rows)
```

Given `user_id = 2`, the query above returns the result:

```
 id | parent_message_id |         created_at
----+-------------------+----------------------------
  2 |                 1 | 2020-05-11 13:50:00.857589
  5 |                   | 2020-05-11 13:52:01.261975
(2 rows)
```

### Sorting the overall results:

> The created_at DESC is able to get the latest child message but does not sort the overall collection. I can solve this by calling .reverse, but wondering if there was a way to fix that as well.

To do the sorting in the database, you can wrap the above query in a cte

example:

```
WITH last_messages AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (COALESCE(parent_message_id, messages.id)) messages.*
FROM messages
JOIN message_participants ON message_participants.message_id = messages.id
WHERE message_participants.user_id = 2
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent_message_id, messages.id), created_at DESC
)
SELECT * FROM last_messages ORDER BY created_at;
```

However, I'm not 100% sure how that would be expressed in AR